# Need help in Calling fox pro program from c# code

Tags: c#, foxpro

I need some help on calling foxprogram from c# code.

We have dedicated machine where we have fox releated program.

**Machine Name :** TestFox

**We have shared folder** \\TestFox\FoxPrograms

I need to call init.prg which is present in \\TestFox\FoxPrograms [It is built in vfp9]

I used the below code

```
        try
        {

            string foxCommand = "init.prg";
            var parse = new FoxApplication();
            parse.DefaultFilePath = @"\\TestFox\FoxPrograms";
            parse.DoCmd(foxCommand);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //I m getting exception 
           //{System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80020009): 
           //Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 
           //0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION)) at VisualFoxpro.Application.DoCmd 
           //(String  bstrCmd)
           //at CallFox.Program.CallFoxPraser(String step) 
           //in   C  :\Users\ssnagendrakumar\documents\ 
           //visual studio 2010\Projects\CallFox\CallFox\Program.cs:line 32}
        }


  I refered vfp9.exe in solution to get FoxApplication()
```

Can someone help me? please

Comment: Why aren't you using `VisualFoxPro.Application` as outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dyfa216%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: @stuartd I tried this aswell but no luck. Would you mind giving me a sample code for your suggestion?

Comment: What is actually IN the INIT.PRG that you need to do, and can it be done using the VFPOleDB such as opening, querying tables, etc?  Or does  it launch a bunch of other elements you need from that.

Comment: INIT.PRG is helper program. Intern we are calling many other prg logic includes business and data updation as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to use the `VisualFoxpro.FoxApplication` class, and you are passing invalid syntax - to execute a VFP program you need to use the [`DO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/fcd9es9w.aspx) command:

```
var parse = new VisualFoxpro.FoxApplication;
string foxCommand = "do init.prg";
parse.DefaultFilePath = @"\\TestFox\FoxPrograms";
parse.DoCmd(foxCommand);
```

Comment: I added VisualFoxpro as namespace

Comment: @saTech: Did you try changing your `foxCommand` string to match @stuartd's?

Comment: I m marking the answer as correct. Thanks Stuartd. Issue was with some dll registration. above code worked for me. Thanks.